# Schema.org vs Microdata

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There are currently separate tags for [microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microdata) and [schema.org](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema.org). These are *technically* different, as Schema.org is a collection of schemas making use of Microdata for marking up semantic data, but most people will see them as one and the same.

It's a shame that searched for one don't return results for the other. Would these be worth combining and setting one as a synonym of the other?

Comment: I think schema.org should be a synonym of microdata. If there is consensus on it we can make that happen.

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the related tags I found and what should be done with each:

- [rich-snippets](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rich-snippets) - 46 questions tagged - Added tag wiki - What search engines show based on semantic data
- [microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microdata) - 38 questions tagged - Edited tag wiki - A type of semantic web markup
- [microformats](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microformats) - 26 questions tagged - Created tag wiki - A type of semantic web markup
- [semantic-web](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantic-web) - 23 questions tagged - Created tag wiki - Providing machine readable data via a schema in web pages
- [schema.org](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema.org) - 20 questions tagged - merged with [microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microdata) - Site that lists all the microdata schemas available that are used by search engines.
- [rdfa](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdfa) - 10 questions tagged - Created tag wiki - A type of semantic web markup